# Select records according to years's last day

Tags: mysql, sql, maxdate

I have table having 26 columns in which first 3 Columns are day,month,year. And rest of columns having some information that i have to show. Now i have to fetch records according to years's last day.
I have tried writing code.

```
select * from subscription_stats where year * 10000 + month * 100 + day = LAST_DAY(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day))
```

But this will fetch records from last day of every month and i want last day of years.And also, When i dont have actual last day in records then this code will not work. So instead of LAST_DAY i want some functionality like MAX date in that month. How can i implement this functionality.

Comment: If you want the last day of the year, then why don't you just hardcode December, or am I missing something?

Comment: Store dates as a single entity

Comment: i can have many records so it must be dynamic. Thats why i can not hardcode it

Comment: Incidentally, 26 columns *can* sometimes be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from subscription_stats
where month = 12 and day = 31;
```

That returns the rows for December 31st.

If you don't have records for all days and you want the last day in the data:

```
select ss.*
from subscription_stats ss
where (ss.month, ss.day) = (select ss2.month, ss2.day
                            subscription_stats ss2
                            where ss2.year = ss.year
                            order by ss2.month desc, ss2.day desc
                           );
```